# ERROR TypeError: google.maps.Travelmode is undefined even though it is defined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to include google maps in my project and I've run into the Error above even though everything should be correct.
If I just search for a location I get there and everything works fine but when I try to display the route, as shown in the google docs I get the Error
Could it be that somehow google isn't recognized?

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then((resp) => {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          resp.coords.latitude,
          resp.coords.longitude
        );
        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
          this.mapElement.nativeElement,
          mapOptions
        );

        this.directionsRenderer.setMap(this.map);        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting location", error);
      });
  }




calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
    this.directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: this.currentLatLng, //takes the current location
        destination: this.currentLatLng,
        waypoints: this.waypointArray,  
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.Travelmode.DRIVING,//here's the problem
        drivingOptions: {
          trafficModel: "pessimistic",
        },
      },
      (response, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The Google script is not yet loaded and therefore google is undefined

Comment: How does that make sense if everything else works, just the travelmode doesn't?
The map loads and I can track my location.

Comment: travelMode is just "Driving", not google.maps.Travelmode.DRIVING   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes

Comment: @ecg8 that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in:
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING